# How to use GestureRecognizer on Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

The problem is, that in order to generate manipulations, GestureRecognizer requires to call its methods "ProcessXXX" (e.g. "ProcessDownEvent").

These methods require "PointerPoint" object.

On winrt I got this point directly from "PointerXXX" event args (e.g. "args.GetCurrentPoint"). However, I don't have this in Windows Phone.

So, my question is: how I can make GestureRecognizer to work on Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Rob Caplan from Microsoft, I have a solution.

CoreWindow is available for Windows Phone, and it has PointerXXX events, which can be used for GestureRecognizer.

Comment: I'm glad to know your solution here. ：)